# Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`? REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can anyone explain why this happen and how can I fix it?

[image: HERE's AN ERROR]

Because I really don't know what cause this error.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error says? Replacing `class` with `className` as react requires?

Comment: In HTML there is an attribute `class`. If you wish to reference that attribute directly in javascript, use the reference `className`.

Comment: In React's JSX part you're writing "HTML" but directly inside a script. And `class` is a reserved word / keyword. Therefore in JSX you use [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) instead, exactly like the warning says.